# Using jquery in a Node.js project to make api request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i am trying to make an api request in a node project using jquery, which I've istalled via `npm install jquery` but I'm getting the error `TypeError: $.post is not a function` even after requiring jquery like so: `const $ = require('jquery')` how can I get Jquery to work? I've seen a lot of examples of people using jquery but the process was not clear to me since I'm new to Node.js
Here is my code

```
const $ = require('jquery')

$.post("https://ticketsoko.nouveta.co.ke/api/index.php", {
    TransactionType: "getEvents"
}, function (data, status) {
    var info = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < info.data.length; i++) {
        ticketSales[i] = info.data[i].totalTicketsSalesAmount;
        events[i] = info.data[i].Events.events_name;
        console.log(events[i]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a capital `Q` for jQuery

So it is `const $ = require('jQuery')` instead of `require('jquery')`.

Comment: It is whatever the module is named. You can hack your module to have it named mamamia if you like :D Having that module up to date does require manual work then ..  But, you could wrap it inside another module with diff name, expose it under that name and still have it synced via original package/module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is step by step hard-to-go-wrong tutorial on how to obtain jQuery into your NodeJs project, then require it in your code and use in a manner similar to what you would do without NodeJs. If you haven't heard of modules and npm and are working with NodeJs, YESTERDAY was the time to have some working knowledge with them.

[click here to see how to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery)

On the other hand, WHY are you using jQ for this? You have entire world of modules to your disposal via npm, there are better modules, more fitted to do HTTP requests with like this one:

[request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Answer (score -2):

JQuery has many methods to handle asynchronous HTTP requests. In order to use jQuery, we need to include the source file of jQuery. The $.ajax() method is used to make the HTTP request.

Note: To use jQuery in Node.js, you need to install it using npm and then require it in your file. However, jQuery is primarily a DOM manipulation library, and Node.js doesn't have a DOM. Therefore, you can't use jQuery in the same way you would in a browser environment.

If you want to use jQuery in a Node.js environment, you can use a package like jsdom to create a DOM environment for jQuery.

Install jquery jsdom: `npm install jquery jsdom`